# How to use google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath in dartlang?

Tags: google-maps, dart

How is the way to use the function to decode a string?

I can not find the way with the native library

```
var path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedStr);
```

----- Soluction ----

```
String str = "ern[pd_cMiAa@\q@l@kAPY`Ad@hCnAr@^HOzAaClCgElBsCfBhA";
var decodedPath = encoding.decodePath(str);
var estimate_line = new Polyline(new PolylineOptions()
        ..path = decodedPath
        ..geodesic = true
        ..strokeColor = '#FF0000'
        ..strokeOpacity = 1.0
        ..strokeWeight = 2
        ..map = map
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `google_maps` package you can import `package:google_maps/google_maps_encoding.dart` and use `encoding.decodePath(path)`. encoding is an optional js library you need to optin with `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=encoding` in your `<script>`.

See [the example with encoding library](https://github.com/a14n/dart-google-maps/tree/master/example/09-libraries/geometry-encodings).

Comment: it is the opposite process of that example, of an encoded string to make it a array of coordinates

Comment: yes. you only have to use an other method. I pointed the example to show you the way to set things up.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question to include the answer

Answer (score 2):

Here i have implemented in native dart 
For encoding reference : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm   Here the encoding algorithm is explained

```
import 'dart:io';

main()
{
var z="eo~fMzva{Fl|cuTgh~oU~bxjDhpptb@";
print(decode(z)); 
}

/** function to decode the string ****/
List decode(var a)
{
var list=a.codeUnits;
var lList=new List();
int index=0;
int len=a.length;
int c=0;

// repeating until all attributes are decoded
do
{   
    var shift=0;
    int result=0;

    // for decoding value of one attribute
    do
    {
        c=list[index]-63;
        result|=(c & 0x1F)<<(shift*5);
        index++;
        shift++;
    }while(c>=32);
    /* if value is negetive then bitwise not the value */
    if(result & 1==1)
    {
        result=~result;
    }
    var result1 = (result >> 1) * 0.00001;
    lList.add(result1);
}while(index<len);

/*adding to previous value as done in encoding */
for(var i=2;i<lList.length;i++)
    lList[i]+=lList[i-2];
return lList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I went to this website https://pub.dev/packages/geo .but I don't see how can I use that using c# or what library should I need ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [geo package](https://pub.dev/packages/geo) to encode/decode path:

```
import 'package:geo/geo.dart';

void main() {
  var decodedPath = const PolylineCodec().decode(str);
}
```